# Передача текста через input radio с javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, input

При выборе пункта Нет, в форме автоматически добавляется текст "Нет", как это правильно реализовать на JS, заранее спасибо!

```
<label for="RadiosYes" id="radios_one">
                    <input type="radio" name="Name" id="RadioYes" value="Да" class="radio-check"/>
                     Да
                </label>
                <label for="RadiosNo" id="radios_two">
                    <input type="radio" name="Name" id="RadioNo" value="Нет" class="radio-check"/>
                     Нет
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="field_container">
                <p class="field" id="NoAgent"><input id="user_agency" type="text" name="UserAgency" class="field-input"/>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#RadioNo").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       $("#user_agency").val("Нет");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="RadiosYes" id="radios_one">
                    <input type="radio" name="Name" id="RadioYes" value="Да" class="radio-check"/>
                     Да
                </label>
                <label for="RadiosNo" id="radios_two">
                    <input type="radio" name="Name" id="RadioNo" value="Нет" class="radio-check"/>
                     Нет
                </label>
         
            <div class="field_container">
                <p class="field" id="NoAgent"><input id="user_agency" type="text" name="UserAgency" class="field-input"/>
                </p>
            </div>
```